# Not able to load image in visual studio code for p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm not able to load image in visual studio code for p5.js. How can I load image in p5.js?
I have created a new project but the images which I have loaded are not working so how can I do to run image in visual studio code for p5.js? Following the reference documents I added preload. You can see I also tried doing this with an image file and it produced the same results.

```
var pic1;
var pic2;
var pic3;
var pic4;
var pic5;
var pic6;
let button;
let posX=0
let posY=0

let list;
let selectedItem = -1;
let drop = false;
let items = ["Apples", "Peaches", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Pears" ];
let itemY = [];

class List {

  constructor(x, y, w, h, itemH, txtSize) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.itemH = itemH;
    this.txtSize = txtSize;
    this.arrwX = this.x + this.w;
    this.arrwY = this.y;
    this.arrwH = this.h;
  }

  press(mx, my) {
    // arrow touches
    if ((mx >= this.arrwX) && (mx <= this.arrwX+this.arrwH) && (my >= this.arrwY) && (my <= this.arrwY+this.arrwH)) {
      if (drop == true) {
        drop = false;
      } else {
        drop = true;
      }
    } // list touches
    if (drop) {
      if (items.length > 0) {
        for (let j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
          if ((mx >= this.x) && (mx <= this.x + this.w) && (my >= itemY[j] ) && (my <= itemY[j] + this.itemH)) {
            selectedItem = j;
            drop = false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  displayFieldString(title) {
    fill(255); // background color
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    fill(0); // text color
    textSize(this.txtSize);
    text(title, this.x + 10, this.y + this.txtSize);
  }

  display() {
    if (selectedItem == -1) {
      this.displayFieldString("Select item:");
    } else {
      this.displayFieldString(items[selectedItem]);
    }
    // arrow
    fill(255); // arrow background color
    rect(this.arrwX, this.arrwY, this.arrwH, this.arrwH);
    fill(0, 255, 0); // arrow color
    triangle(this.arrwX+5, this.arrwY+5, this.arrwX+this.arrwH-5, this.arrwY+5, this.arrwX+this.arrwH/2, this.arrwY+this.arrwH-5);
    // listItems
    if ((items.length > 0) && (drop)) {
      for (let j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
        itemY[j] = (this.y + this.h) + j*this.itemH;
        fill(255);
        rect(this.x, itemY[j], this.w, this.itemH);
        fill(0);
        textSize(this.txtSize);
        text(items[j], this.x + 10, itemY[j] + this.txtSize);
      }
    }
    if (!drop) {
      rect(this.x, this.y + this.h, this.w, 0);
    }
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 400);
  list = new List(100, 100, 120, 24, 24, 16);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  list.display();
}

function mousePressed() {
  //list.press(mouseX, mouseY);
}

const rightwall=350;
const height=450;
function preload(){
  pic1=loadImage("5.png")
  pic2=loadImage("Iron ore.jpg")
  pic4=loadImage("blastfurnace.jpg")
  pic5=loadImage("coal2.jpg")
  pic6=loadImage("limestone.jpg")
  pic3=loadImage("reactions.jpg")
  
  
}
function setup(){
  createCanvas(600,600);
  background("blue");
  button=createButton("CLICK TO LOAD INTO FURNACE") 
  button.position(150,330);
  button.mousePressed(changeBG);
  
  noLoop();
}
function changeBG() {
  let val = random(65);
  background(val);
  loop();
  playAnim=true;
  draw();
  posX=0;
  posY=0;
  // background will be overwritten with 220
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
 // text(mouseX + "," + mouseY, 20, 20);
  // If the 'a' key is pressed, draw the following text in the canvas
if (key === 'a'){
  textSize(22);
  text('a key was pressed!', width / 2, height / 2);
}
  let s='BLAST FURNACE';
textSize(23);
fill(0,102,153);
 text(s,50, 10,300, 400);
 
  img1=image(pic1, 320, 30, 170,210)
  
  img6=image(pic6,posX,160,70,70)
  img2=image(pic2,posX, 80, 70, 70)
  
  img5=image(pic5,posX,20,50,50)
  img4=image(pic4,posX,posY-300,220,220)
 img3=image(pic3,20,340-posY,230, 230)
  if (playAnim) {
  posX=constrain(posX+1,0,rightwall-30)
  posY=constrain(posX-1,posY,height-50)
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about two things: 1) what do you mean by "not able to load image in visual studio code", and 2) how are you accessing your sketch. Re: #1 look at the JavaScript console in your web browser. Are there any errors? Re: #2 specifically are you trying to open your sketch with a file path URL (starting with `file:///`), or are you using a development server such as the VS Code Live Server?

Comment: i am using vs code live server

Comment: In that case I would suspect that there is an issue with the image files not being in the same location as the HTML file you are loading. However in order to give you an actual answer you would need to share any error messages you're seeing and possible a more complete example of the problem including the HTML file and a description of the folder layout.

Answer (score 0):

Your file path is wrong:

`p5.js says: It looks like there was a problem loading your image. Try checking if the file path (https://preview.p5js.org/limestone.jpg) is correct, hosting the file online, or running a local server. (More info at https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Local-server)`